# Key errors for object after converting it to a string in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have three csv files we can call a, b, and c.  File a has geographic information including zip codes.  File b has statistical data.  File c has only zip codes.

I used pandas to convert `a` and `b` to dataframes (`a_df` and `b_df`) which I used to join on information that was a shared column between those two dataframes (`intermediate_df`).  File `c` was read and converted to a dataframe that had the zipcode as an integer type.  I had to convert that to string so zipcodes are not treated as integers.  However, `c_df` treats that column as objects after I convert it to string which means then I cannot do a join between `c_df` and intermediate_df to make final_df.

To illustrate what I mean:

```
a_data = pd.read_csv("a.csv")
b_data = pd.read_csv("b.csv", dtype={'zipcode': 'str'})
a_df = pd.DataFrame(a_data)
b_df = pd.DataFrame(b_data)

# file c conversion
c_data = pd.read_csv("slcsp.csv", dtype={'zipcode': 'str'})
print ("This is c data types: ", c_data.dtypes)
c_conversion = c_data['zipcode'].apply(str)
print ("This is c_conversion data types: ", c_conversion.dtypes)
c_df = pd.DataFrame(c_conversion)
print ("This is c_df data types: ", c_df.dtypes)

# Joining on the two common columns to avoid duplicates
joined_ab_df = pd.merge(a_df, a_df, on =['state', 'area'])

# Dropping columns that are not needed anymore
ab_for_analysis_df = joined_ab.drop(['county_code','name', 'area'], axis=1)

# Time to analyze this dataframe. Let's pick out only the silver values for 
a specific attribute
silver_only_df = (ab_for_analysis_df[filtered_df.metal_name == 'Silver'])

# Getting second lowest value of silver only
sorted_silver = silver_only_df.groupby('zipcode')['rate'].nsmallest(2)
sorted_silver_df = sorted_silver.to_frame()

print ("We cleaned up our data. Let's join the dataframes.")
print ("Final result...")
print (c_df.dtypes)
final_df = pd.merge(sorted_silver_df,c_df, on ='zipcode')
```

This is what we get after running it:

```
This is c_data types:  zipcode     object
rate       float64
dtype: object
This is c_conversion_data types:  object
This is c_df data types:  zipcode    object
dtype: object
zipcode    object
dtype: object

We cleaned up our data. Let's join the dataframes.
This is the final result...
KeyError: 'zipcode'
```

Any idea why it changed data types and how do I then fix it so it all joins in the end?

Comment: Can you add `print(c_df.columns)` and  `print(sorted_silver_df.columns)`

Comment: So the second to last line: `print (c_df.dtypes)` doesn't print either? That's bizarre. I recommend using ipython/jupyter and the `%debug` magic function, that way you can step through these kind of errors.

Comment: It's a weird problem.  @AndyHayden.  The print c_df.dtypes works though it gives weird results

Answer (score 2):

If convert to `str` always output `dtype` is object.

For check `strings` need check `type`:

```
print (c_data['zipcode'].apply(type))
```

To your last error:

Need [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html), because else `zipcode` is index, not column:

```
sorted_silver_df = silver_only_df.groupby('zipcode')['rate'].nsmallest(2).reset_index()
final_df = pd.merge(sorted_silver_df,c_df, on ='zipcode')
```

Thanks, [Andy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46843224/key-errors-for-object-after-converting-it-to-a-string-in-pandas/46843291#comment80634207_46843291) for alternative (untested):

```
sorted_silver_df = silver_only_df.groupby('zipcode', as_index=False)['rate'].nsmallest(2)
final_df = pd.merge(sorted_silver_df,c_df, on ='zipcode')
```

Or use `left_index=True` and `riht_on` in [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html):

```
sorted_silver = silver_only_df.groupby('zipcode')['rate'].nsmallest(2)
sorted_silver_df = sorted_silver.to_frame()
final_df = pd.merge(sorted_silver_df,c_df, right_on ='zipcode', left_index=True)
```

Comment: can also use `as_index=False` in the groupby (instead of `reset_index`)

Comment: Thanks, I add it to answer. But sometimes it does not work, so rather I add notice untested ;)

Comment: Thanks.  I can't seem to get that to work either:

    `50    <class 'str'>`
    `Name: zipcode, dtype: object`
    `This is c_data types:  object`
    `This is c_df data types:  zipcode    object`
    `dtype: object`
    `zipcode    object`
    `dtype: object`
    
    `We cleaned up our data. Let's join the dataframes.`
    `Final result...raise ValueError('len(right_on) must equal the number '`
    `ValueError: len(right_on) must equal the number of levels in the index` 
   ` of "left"`

Comment: So it does not work? Then problem is in data - maybe some whitespaces I guess. Is possible share your data - gdocs, dropbox or send by email if not confidental data?

Comment: I tried both of those.  I can share that data too since it's public though a gdoc or whatever. I have a meeting at in a few minutes, but I'll send that off so you can see if I am missing something

Comment: OK, if want send me daata to my email it is in my profile.

Comment: @Christina Smithers you forgot my comment ? What does c_df.columns  and silver_df.columns give the output as

Comment: @Bharathshetty - I think problem has to be in index, because columns of `c_df data` is possible check by `print ("This is c_df data types: ",  .c_df.dtypes)` in OP question

Comment: @jezrael I asked that because at the end there `c_df.dtypes`  is not printed. Im asking to check whether the dataframe exists with columns.

Comment: @Bharathshetty - Are you sure `This is c_df data types:  zipcode    object` ?

Comment: @Bharathshetty - Or do you think some wtitespaces in columns names? ;)

Comment: No no Im asking the last two lines `print (c_df.dtypes)
final_df = pd.merge(sorted_silver_df,c_df, on ='zipcode')` If you see the output OP doesn't put the c_dfdtypes there. I was bit confused but OP typed the result i guess

Comment: I think because `pd.merge(sorted_silver_df,c_df, on ='zipcode')` failed...

Comment: @Bharathshetty,  Apologies on the wait. 

Here's the code for the:

`silver_only_df = (plans_zips_for_analysis_df[plans_zips_for_analysis_df.metal_level == 'Silver'])`
`print (silver_only_df)`
`print (silver_only_df.dtypes)`
      Which gives:

    `plan_id state metal_level    rate zipcode`
    `0        74449NR9870320    GA      Silver  298.62   30726`
    `[890741 rows x 5 columns]`
   `plan_id         object`
    `state           object`
    `metal_level     object`
    `rate           float64`
    `zipcode         object`
    `dtype: object`